# $match query problem using aggregation with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to do a very simple query joining two collections using aggregation.

I have two collections,

```
productSchema = new Schema({
    product: { type: String },
    price: { type: Number},
})

const inventoriesSchema= new Schema({
    date: { type: Date},
    products: [productSchema],
})
```

Now i want to bring all the products and inside of every product i want to bring the inventory.

This is what i am doing.

```
    productModel.aggregate([
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: 'inventories',
                let: {
                    'product': { $toString: '$_id' }
                },
                pipeline: [
                    {
                        $match: {
                            'products._id': '$$product'
                        }
                    },
                ],
                as: 'inventory',
            }
        },
      ])
```

i tried a lot of ways... with $toObjectId $toString... using $expr also like this...

```
                     {
                        $match: {                              
                            $expr: {
                                $and: [
                                    { $eq: ['$product._id', { $toString: "$$product" }] }
                                ]

                            }
                        }
                    }
```

What i am doing wrong... ???

Comment: What is the relation between `products` & `inventories` collection which field has to be used to JOIN ? Does `product` field is what we need to look in `inventories` collection `products` array ? Please provide sample docs & required o/p..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below aggregation query which uses [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/index.html#in-aggregation) to check whether an expression exists in array or not :

Assuming your `product` field in **products** Coll is key to join & needs to be checked in `products` array of **inventories** Coll.

```
productModel.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'inventories',
            let: { 'product': '$product' }, // create local variable for products
            pipeline: [
                { $match: { $expr: { $in: [ "$$product",  "$products" ] } } } // check product from products Coll exists in products of inventories Coll
            ],
            as: 'inventory'
        }
    }
  ])
```

Comment: uhh.... i was missing $in to check the _id inside the array... i was just trying to $match the inventories that contains the product inside... thanks for your quick answer